# select instance of a class from many instances conditioned on a slot?

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

Assume I have several instances of an `S4` class, just like in this example.

```
setClass("myClass",representation(name = "character",
          description = "character")

my1 <- new("myClass",name = "my1",description = "Some test.")
my2 <- new("myClass",name = "my2",description = "Some try.")
my3 <- new("myClass",name = "my3",description = "Some more elaborate test.")
```

I would like to give back the name of all classes (i.e. name slot or object name) that contains the word `test`. If I just use `grep` on single slot it does work partly:

```
grep("test",my1@description,value=T)
```

I end up with the whole expresion "Some test". Of course I could put all of these slots in a list and apply over them.  But still I'd just end up with the description itself without knowing to which name they belong.

So, how can I find the instances I want?

Would you rather organize a bunch of instances of a class in a separate environment or a list of Instances?

Answer (score 1):

This command will find the instances:

```
unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,
              function(x)
                if (class(x)[1] == "myClass")
                  if (any(grep("test", x@description))) return(x@name)))
```

The class of each object in the global environment is checked. If it is `myClass` and the `description` slot contains `"test"`, both the value in the `name` slot and the object name will be returned.

Output for your example:

```
  my1   my3 
"my1" "my3"
```